# Can landlords refuse to sublet mid-month?

Tags: united-states, residential-lease, texas, sublease

I've encountered a big corporate landlord in West Campus, Austin, Texas, that's only willing to reassign the lease at the start of a month, saying that they don't prorate rents.

(Interestingly enough, all of their original leases are from mid-August to end of July, with 12 equal instalments.)

If someone is done with classes mid-May, and wants to sublet to someone else for the summer session, would it be legal for a Texas landlord to deny a sublet from mid-May, and require that the reassignment be from June 1 instead?

Comment: As a practical workaround, perhaps the tenant could take the assignee as a "houseguest" from mid May through May 31st.

Comment: @phoog, pretty sure it'll violate the lease, otherwise, there's also not much point in actual re-assignment, if the original tenant would still be liable for the new guest after original tenant's departure

Comment: my suggestion assumes that the landlord cannot prohibit a 2-week stay by a houseguest even if he could prohibit the long-term occupation of the unit by a third party.  Granted, it's probably not completely aboveboard, but it does seem a practical solution, and possibly a defensible solution.

Comment: Read the lease and what it says about subletting. That is nearly always a clause in every lease.